# Images on FlatList will not render on android device samsung s9 but renders on web - react native

Tags: react-native, flatlist

Everything seems okay, the images all render on web but when we run it with expo on mobile the images don't seem to render on android.

```
  <View>
       <FlatList
         data={DATA}
         renderItem={({item}) => 
       <View style={{height: 120,width:'100%', display: 'flex',flexDirection:'row', 
                               justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center'}}>
       <View style={{ flex: 1.2, padding: 5}}>
   <Image source={item.image} style={{height:100, width:100, borderRadius: 100}}/>
</View>
<View style={{ flex: 1.8, padding:10}}>
<View style={{display:'flex', flexDirection:'row', alignItems:'center'}}>
<Text variant='header' style={{fontSize: 15}}>{item.user}</Text>
<Image source={item.verifyImg} style={{height:15, width:15, borderRadius: 100, marginLeft:5}}/></View>
<View style={{display:'flex', flexDirection:'row', alignItems:'center', flex: 1.5, marginTop:-10}}> <Text variant='xs'>{item.handle}</Text> <Text variant='xs'>{item.career}</Text></View>
   <Text variant='xs'>{item.cost}</Text>
   </View>
<View style={{flex:1.2}}>
                                                               
<TouchableOpacity style={[Styles.centerElement, 
{ width: '100%', height: 60, padding: 10, display:'flex', justifyContent:'center', alignItems: 'center', 
}]} 
>
<CustomButton  onPress={() => {console.log('pressed')}} label='invite'  borderRadius={5} backgroundColor='#FF406E'  color='white'
                                                                                                                   />
 </TouchableOpacity>   
   </View>
   </View> }
   keyExtractor={item => item.id}/>
</View>
```